# Why is the question asking for textbooks on sexual physiology too broad?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Are there any textbooks about sexual physiology and practices?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18786/99)

This question is closed as too-broad and perhaps self-help, but I'm unable to see how. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Related: [“Give me a resource” questions](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/997)